# How tableau connect to Arangodb?

Tags: tableau-api

How does tableau connect to arangoDB? Is there any ODBC driver for arangodb as a new datasource for tableau desktop/server on windows?

Answer (score 1):

there is at the moment no official Tableau driver for ArangoDB. Maybe you will find a driver on their [community](https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/community/) page. If you really need a binding you should ask Tableau if they could support the database. The more people ask the more likely it is that they will include official support in a future release. I am happy to provide them with help in case they decide to support ArangoDB.

Comment: Yes,  I asked tableau technical support for this.  There is no official arangoDB odbc driver right now.  I have raised a case to Tableau team for future release with it. I am still research for it. Hopefully let me know if you have any alternative answer. Thanks